# Logger not printing the stack trace in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

I am not able to print the stack trace of the logger in my eclipse console.

log4j.properties

```
  log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,console

  #Console Appender 
  log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
  log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
  log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] [%t %d{hh:mm:ss}] (%F:%M:%L) %m%n

  #Custom assignments
  log4j.logger.controller=INFO,console
  log4j.logger.service=INFO,console

  #Disable additivity
  log4j.additivity.controller=false
  log4j.additivity.service=false
```

Service layer:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<MRPSDepositHistory> getDepositDetails(String searchCondition,
        String searchText, String jtSorting, int startPaginationVal,
        int endPaginationVal) {
    String searchConditionEmpty = ManagementConstants.SEARCHCONDITIONNONE;

    List<MRPSDepositHistory> fileNetStatus = new ArrayList<MRPSDepositHistory>();
    try {
        if (!searchConditionEmpty.equalsIgnoreCase(searchCondition)) {
            if (searchCondition.equalsIgnoreCase(ManagementConstants.DEPOSITNUMBERKEY)) {
                fileNetStatus = mrpsDepositHistoryDao.findByDepositNumber(
                        searchCondition, Short.valueOf(searchText), jtSorting,
                        startPaginationVal, endPaginationVal);
            } else {
                fileNetStatus = mrpsDepositHistoryDao.findBySearchText(
                        searchCondition, searchText, jtSorting,
                        startPaginationVal, endPaginationVal);
            }
        } else {
            fileNetStatus = mrpsDepositHistoryDao.findByRestrictions(
                    searchCondition, searchText, jtSorting);
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        logger.error("ERROR:" + e);
    }
    return fileNetStatus;
}
```

Log getting printed in console now in eclipse:

> [ERROR] [http-bio-8080-exec-9 03:46:16] (MrpsDepositHistoryServiceImpl.java:getDepositDetails:57) ERROR:java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"353453454" Radix:10

What I have made wrong in the above code.

Comment: The wrong is the `+`... That basically does rewrites to `logger.error("Error: " + e.toString())`. Instead use a `,`... `logger.error("Error:", e)` which will print the stacktrace.

Comment: Deinum still not working after changing to e.toString()

Comment: Have you actually read my comment? Instead of a `+` use `,` which is what I wrote. The `toString` is what you already had (and was there for clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
logger.error("ERROR:"+ e);
```

by

```
logger.error("ERROR:", e);
```

Former one actually concatenates strings and calls `Logger.error(String)` which simply logs that concatenated string. But later one calls `Logger.error(String, Throwable)` where the `Throwable` (super class of `Exception`) is managed separately.

Comment: Also, make sure to use the logger.error(String, Throwable), and not another one that doesn't support throwable in the parameters. The above didn't work for me till I switched to that specific logger.error with throwable